# Passing Scanner Input Into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a simple program which has 2 classes, one with set methods, and the other with the main, executable method.

First Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Practice
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ArrayList<Double> sales = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public Practice(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void addSales(double sale)
    {
        sales.add(sale);
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> returnSales()
    {
        return sales;
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PracticeExecutable {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double sale;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Enter first name: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please Enter last name: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();

        Practice employee = new Practice(firstName, lastName);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter sale amount or -1 to quit: ");
            sale = input.nextDouble();
            if(sale == -1)
                break;
        }while(sale != -1);

        employee.addSales(sale);
        input.close();


        System.out.println("Name: " + employee.getFirstName() + " " + 
            employee.getLastName());
        System.out.println("Sales: " + employee.returnSales());
    }

}
```

I am trying to pass the user input into the ArrayList sales, then print the sales that were input, but it seems it is only recognizing '-1' as a sale. I can't seem to locate the issue though.

Comment: What you typing when program ask you for sale amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in loop you only check if sale is invalid and do nothing with valid sale values. When you exit from loop (sale input is -1) you add that wrong value to list. For change this simple move employe.addSales(sale) to loop like this:

```
       do {
            System.out.println("Please enter sale amount or -1 to quit: ");
            sale = input.nextDouble();
            if(sale == -1) break;
            employee.addSales(sale);

        } while(sale != -1);
```

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how I overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Carefully observe this line:

> employee.addSales(sale);

This is the line that adds the sales to the ArrayList. This line only runs once, and it always has the value of -1. Afterall that's when the loop breaks when sales is -1. So it simply adds -1 to the ArrayList, nothing else.
What you need to do is **move this line inside the do while block**. Just make sure that the sale is added to the ArrayList when the value of sales is not equal to -1. Rest will be fine.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks!